# mvvm? mvvmc? or am I doing it all wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am currently building a wpf application in which the view models call functions in a singleton logics class in order to get their models or modify existing models... The logics class is responsible for creating models and notifying the view models of relevant changes. Now my question is am I doing it correctly or is there a better way to do it? Because it seems like no one else is doing it the same way - and I am new to wpf and I don't want to begin all wrong.

My application gets certain objects from db and displays them on a graph, there is one view model responsible for displaying the data, the rest receive user input in order to modify the data.

Comment: Dont worry about the pattern so much. What you describe sounds about right. Use VMs to mainly control the UI, use Models for your domain logic and use your judgment to keep things simple and get the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a different opinion to some of the opinions given to you so far. In my personal opinion, you should have one view model per view. To be fair, all I have based this opinion on is how well it works. The way that I see it, the beauty of utilising the MVVM pattern is its simplicity... just put all of the data properties and functionality into each view model that its related view requires.

I would disagree with the comment that @SebastianEdelmeier made about using Dependency Injection instead of Singleton classes. Dependency Injection is really not much more than passing interfaced data to classes through the constructor. Whilst I am not against Dependency Injection, it should be noted that even the MSDN Dependency Injection page has been labelled as `Retired Content`.

I have many `...Manager` classes (others may call them Service classes) that are all Singleton classes... they need to be so that I can ensure that there will only be one instance of each. They present absolutely no problems with unit testing because they are all interfaced and I have provided `...MockManger` classes.

I do however accept @SebastianEdelmeier's point that the code inside the actual `...Manager` classes is trickier to test, but it's mostly just basic code that saves a file to the hard drive or sends an e-mail. This is the kind of code that has been thoroughly tested by Microsoft and doesn't even really need (unit) testing. Even so, it *is* possible to test them.

However, these service classes all do something unique, requiring references to particular dlls or resources that the view models do not have access to... therefore they provide some service to the view models *that the view models cannot provide themselves*. It sounds a bit like you have put functionality into your Singleton class that could (and probably should) be in your view model. I would advise against that practice.

Think of the view model providing everything to the view... the data, the functionality, access to service functionality, etc. The only reason to use service classes is to provide some service to the view models *that the view models cannot provide themselves*. If the functionality doesn't fall into this category, and your view model *could* provide it for itself, then it should.

One of the main exceptions to this in my mind would be if you had some kind of `Repository` class following the Repository pattern... the view model *could* create new class instances, but using the repository pattern reduces code repetition... it could be that that is what your Singleton class is for in which case, that's just fine.

---

You'll see that someone has voted to close your question. This is because you have posted a rather subjective question, which could have many different answers but has no single correct answer. You may find that your question gets closed or even deleted because of this reason. While I understand your reason for posting such a question, you really should try to avoid these types of questions in the future.

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" - `answer.Paragraphs.First().Split(' ').Count(a => a.Contains("opinion")) // returns 4` :)

Comment: I think the logics name is misleading, it's more like a class that controls all communication to the model, kinda like a controller but not exactly, anyway I think I now know how I want to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You have already encountered the MVVM issue #1 - there's many different ways of doing it, MVVM is a pattern, not a framework.

Specifics: The viewmodel is the one doing its own change notification (using INotifyPropertyChanged), which is one of its core tasks. I'd keep change notification out of the business logic, it's a view-dependant issue and has no *functionality*.

About singletons, I can only advise you to develop your classes **without** singleton implementations and have a Dependency Injection container (like Ninject) *resolve them as singletons*. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of hardly testable code (and a lot of redundancy). Static stuff can be tested but when it comes to mocking, they get really nasty.

Comment: What do you mean by the view model is responsible for its own change notification, I am using inotifypropertychanged, but when the user decides to limit the data showed by the graph on an other viewmodel I use the logics to call a relevant event.

Comment: And I will have a look at the ninject